# Customized error message on loading error of PDF in PDFTron

Tags: pdftron

I am working with PDFTron - WebViewer,

Want to know how to handle PDF loading errors and showing customized message, in case of web-viewer

Regards
Bhupesh

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this right now is to modify the ErrorModal component in the UI and replace the error messages there. You'll need to string match the old message and replace it with your own.

The component is located at ui/src/components/ErrorModal/ErrorModal.js and you'll want to change the onError function.

This link describes more about how to edit and build the UI https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/ui/advanced-customization

Answer (score 0):

WebViewer has methods that let you display a modal Warning message box, which can be dismissed with its Confirm button or a click outside the dialog, or you can display a modal Error box which has no dismiss buttons and requires you to hit [F5] to refresh the page.

- https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/UI.html#.showWarningMessage
- https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/UI.html#.displayErrorMessage

Using these is more straightforward than editing the UI code from the pdftron github repo.